# Constructing a type based on the object in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am in need of extracting a type from an object literal that I am constructing by hand. I have the following:

```
const makeFunc: { key: string, val: (p: TParam) => TResult } = <TParam, TResult>(p: TParam) => doSomething(p);

const myObj = {
    getSomething: makeFunc(a),
    getSomethingElse: makeFunc(b)
}
```

Let's assume `a` is of type `A` and makeFunc(a) is of type `AR` and similarly `b` is of type `B` and makeFunc(b) is of type `BR`. Now I need a type that resembles something like this:

```
interface extractedType {
    getSomething: (a: A) => AR,
    getSomethingElse: (b: B) => BR
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? If so, could someone throw some light or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I don't currently have access to a computer, so I can't verify this, but something like this should work,

```
interface extractedType { 
        getSomething: <A, AR> (a: A) => AR, 
        getSomethingElse: <B, BR> (b: B) => BR 
    }
```

you might have to play around with it a bit, hopefully it helps!

Source

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

---

**Edit:**
Link to thread that might be related, see comments.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44078574/7307141

Comment: What I needed to know was how I can extract this interface type using a piece of code. I know what the resultant interface type would be, but given an object literal, I need a function that would extract the resultant interface type I showed.

Comment: Hmm... Okay, that is more difficult, and I don&#39;t have a good answer for that, I post a link to a thread that might be related, good luck!