# How do you annotate an unnamed arrow function in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
export default () => (<div>hi</div>)
```

I'd like to annotate it as a **react stateless** function without *giving it a name*.

A named example would be:

```
const it: React.SFC = () => (<div>hi</div>)
export default it;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't.

And stackoverflow won't accept answers that don't have at least 30 characters.

Answer (score 2):

The types of variables declared within `export default` statements can be [asserted](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html) using `as`

```
export default (() => <div>Hi</div>) as React.SFC<{}>
```

Comment: From the page you linked: "TypeScript's type assertion is purely you telling the compiler that you know about the types better than it does, and that it should not second guess you." It appears that `as` is a *runtime* type assertion, not a *compile-time* assertion.

Comment: [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) compiles to JavaScript. [Any types that you assert using `as` are stripped away at compile-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078205/how-to-check-the-object-type-on-runtime-in-typescript) @jasonszhao