# Enforce string type to be part of array of string in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following interface:

```
interface Option {
  options: string[];
  symbolOption: string;
}
```

How can I enforce that the `symbolOption` must be included in the `options` array?

#### Example of what I need

This will be OK:

```
const option: Option = {
  options: ['a', 'b'],
  symbolOption: 'a' // ✅ OK
};
```

But this will *not* be OK:

```
const option: Option = {
  options: ['a', 'b'],
  symbolOption: 'c' //  `c` is not included in the `options` list.
};
```

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgMK4DOYUcoYAPAFDLIAqyEAHpCACaHLFSgDmANDTSMWEdpwxZcBENzLgKdfmgB8VFcgDeQ7JhyyAXPQDaAXQDcQwgE8AtgCNsAG0n6jqYwCJdU2Z9PGIACuDtAWVAC+VFQIRGDIcISuuMgAvMiKIqwcXCR8yqhZYjnJ+HGk5IoFKioAFNjuAJRparTYllQA9J30ABbAnADuwE5OyPYoqADSBjFxyD76AOLY2GxpCUl6uLXabduGyF5wnsqe9v6CtDYOzqVGnifI3ciAoORoU5GNHS8AQkHxMD9IYjMYgbDxCYfWaxWTxRa4X5wdbpRKlXY6A6EIzHU7Ic6XKx2RwuA4PBCeZ49QC8G4AWXeQAAMEAzkANkOD4qAEE4gmwIOtQMggSgGQjZCynAMwAA6L6WIA) work for you?

Answer (score 1):

This works ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgDwAqAfMgN4BQyVy2mOIAzgFzIEDaAugNyXUMCeAWwBG2ADYYsuFgR4BfcuQD0S1gAtgDZAHdgYscmEpUAaSbkEuBmBp1cAcWzYAJi0n08AcjifkAH2RPYU8SAF4yXipaKUYWNm9PABpA4I5EyOQBEXF3aUCfZBVkQFByNBNyOR5lVQAhAFcbMA0tXX1kEGwbIzLzS0YbaPoauFc0O3wE-xSQ5HCKalsY5mR4n2SgzzSMrNEJcZZPBF8iwF4NwBZd5AADBEvkTXbOu5AEMTrnCGcn5CaUS8GrW5iTRgAB0FS4QA)) though I am not sure whether providing the generic arguments of `'a' | 'b'` will suit your requirement or not.

```
interface Option<T> {
    options: T[];
    symbolOption: T;
}

// This will be OK:
const optionGood: Option<'a' | 'b'> = {
    options: ['a', 'b'],
    symbolOption: 'a' // ✅ OK
};

// But this will not be OK:
const optionBad: Option<'a' | 'b'> = {
    options: ['a', 'b'],
    symbolOption: 'c' //  `c` is not included in the `options` list.
};
```

Here is another alternative courtesy of `jcalz` ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgMK4DOYUcoYAPAFDLIAqyEAHpCACaHLFSgDmANDTSMWEdpwxZcBENzLgKdfmgB8VFcgDeQ7JhyyAXPQDaAXQDcQwgE8AtgCNsAG0n6jqYwCJdU2Z9PGIACuDtAWVAC+VFQIRGDIcISuuMgAvMiKIqwcXCR8yqhZYjnJ+HGk5IoFKioAFNjuAJRparTYllQA9J30ABbAnADuwE5OyPYoqADSBjFxyD76AOLY2GxpCUl6uLXabduGyF5wnsqe9v6CtDYOzqVGnifI3ciAoORoU5GNHS8AQkHxMD9IYjMYgbDxCYfWaxWTxRa4X5wdbpRKlXY6A6EIzHU7Ic6XKx2RwuA4PBCeZ49QC8G4AWXeQAAMEAzkANkOD4qAEE4gmwIOtQMggSgGQjZCynAMwAA6L6WIA)).

```
interface OptionConstraint<
  T extends string,
  O extends OptionConstraint<T, O>
> {
  options: T[];
  symbolOption: O["options"][number];
}

const asOption = <T extends string, O extends OptionConstraint<T, O>>(o: O) =>
  o;

// This will be OK:
const optionGood = asOption({
  options: ["a", "b"],
  symbolOption: "a" // ✅ OK
});

// But this will not be OK:
const optionBad = asOption({
  options: ["a", "b"],
  symbolOption: "c" //  `c` is not included in the `options` list.
});
```

Comment: Once could use [generic type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgMK4DOYUcoYAPAFDLIAqyEAHpCACaHLFSgDmANDTSMWEdpwxZcBENzLgKdfmgB8VFcgDeQ7JhyyAXPQDaAXQDcQwgE8AtgCNsAG0n6jqYwCJdU2Z9PGIACuDtAWVAC+VFQIRGDIcISuuMgAvMiKIqwcXCR8yqhZYjnJ+HGk5IoFKioAFNjuAJRparTYllQA9J30ABbAnADuwE5OyPYoqADSBjFxyD76AOLY2GxpCUl6uLXabduGyF5wnsqe9v6CtDYOzqVGnifI3ciAoORoU5GNHS8AQkHxMD9IYjMYgbDxCYfWaxWTxRa4X5wdbpRKlXY6A6EIzHU7Ic6XKx2RwuA4PBCeZ49QC8G4AWXeQAAMEAzkANkOD4qAEE4gmwIOtQMggSgGQjZCynAMwAA6L6WIA) to get a similar result; not sure if that's what OP wants though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, it would be as simple as:

```
interface Option {
  options: Array<'a'|'b'>;
  symbolOption: string;
}
```

**Edit** 
Edit based on comments.

What you are asking isn't possible, TypeScript is largely a compile type check, you can't have a dynamic type value to represent an interface type.

Have a read of [How to check the object type on runtime in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078205/how-to-check-the-object-type-on-runtime-in-typescript) to understnad what can and can't be done at runtime

Comment: This does not enforce `symbolOption` to be a member of the `options` array. In addition to that, I don't want to create a hard-coded array type.

Comment: Is it really impossible? Because in TS objects, I can do a similar thing with generics and `keyof T`... Anyways. PS: The downvote isn't mine.

Comment: All good, haven't had my coffee yet. 
`keyof T` is different though isn't it? T would be defined at compile time? I'd be very surprised if it is possible