# How typescript compares declared types

Tags: typescript

```
interface SStitle {
  title: string;
  }
  const x:SStitle = { title: "AZ5"};

  if(???){...}esle{...} //x === SStitle
```

I have an interface SStitle.I want to write in `if (???)` such logic that type X is compared with type SStitle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check the object type on runtime in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078205/how-to-check-the-object-type-on-runtime-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one important thing to note. Typescript defines types (with `interface` and `type` keywords). And as TS is compiled to JavaScript, types are completely removed from output JS file.

So to make sure that `x` is of type `SStitle` in run time, we should rely on some properties of `SStitle` which will be preserved after compilation.

In TS this is achieved using [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

So your code with type guard will look like

```
interface SStitle {
    title: string;
}
const x: SStitle = { title: "AZ5" };

// This function is type guard, which works during compilation and during run time.
function isSStitle (x: any): x is SStitle {
    return x.title !== undefined;
}

if (isSStitle(x)) {
    console.log("x is SStitle");
} else{
    console.log("x is NOT SStitle");}
```

Comment: It also makes sense to make type guards accept `unknown` not `any`