# How to check custom interface type in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have

```
interface A {
  a_id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface B {
 b_id: string;
 name: string;
}
```

Now,I want to check an object say:

```
const myObj : A|B = {b_id: '1', name: 'one'};
```

How to check the type and determine whether it belongs to `A` or `B` ?

I tried [few links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078205/how-to-check-the-object-type-on-runtime-in-typescript) but shouldn't it be more easier to get the type ?

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript) interesting.

Comment: @Ivan Your link also says, there no way to check an interface at runtime (what I was thinking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: the question as stated doesn't indicate that the request is to be able to distinguish the type without checking properties.  Unfortunately, that is impossible; TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, which is what actually runs.  And TypeScript's type system, where interfaces like `A` and `B` are found, is completely [erased](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when the code is compiled.  So there is no `A` or `B` at runtime to check.

If you want to be able to distinguish, at runtime, whether `myObj` is `A` or `B`, you need to write JavaScript code that does this... such as checking properties.  What you *can* do is use TypeScript to help you write this code and give it typings so that the compiler also understands that your property check narrows an `A | B` to an `A` or a `B`.  And that's what the rest of this answer (and the other question's answer) tells you. Good luck!

---

The [other question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44078574/2887218) suggests that you write a [user-defined type guard function](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), which will definitely work; the idea is that you tell the compiler what you consider to be a good way to distinguish between `A` and `B`, and it will let you use that function to do so.

An easier way to do it in your case is to use the `in` operator, which [can be used as a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#type-guards-inferred-from--in-operator) (since TypeScript 2.7).  For example:

```
declare const obj: A | B;
if ("b_id" in obj) {
  // obj is a B in here
  console.log(obj.name.toUpperCase());
} else {
  // obj is an A in here
  console.log(obj.a_id.toUpperCase());
}
```

Note that this is technically unsafe, since it's possible to have an object of type `A | B` which isn't distinguishable that way:

```
function getEvilAorB(): A | B {
  interface EvilA extends A {
    b_id: number;
  }
  const evilA: EvilA = { name: "", a_id: "", b_id: 123 };
  return evilA; // okay, EvilA extends A extends A | B
}
```

Notice that `getEvilAorB()` returns a valid `A`, which is therefore a valid `A | B`, but unfortunately it will fail the above test because of the numeric `name` property:

```
const evilA = getEvilAorB();
if ("b_id" in evilA) {
  console.log(evilA.b_id.toUpperCase()); // compiles but  at runtime
  // TypeError! evilA.name.toUpperCase is not a function
}
```

If you aren't concerned about such edge cases, then the `in` type guard is probably sufficient.  Otherwise you should consider either writing a user-defined type guard, or making your interfaces members of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) which is a conventional and supported way to have the compiler distinguish between union members.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQzlwD6wAJgFzIDOYUoA5gNy74hwC2EF1tIjuAvrlyhIsRCgBCmZsgBGxclRr0meZKw5dlvVYJy4YAVxAIwwAPYhkdCGACiAN2AAbVOagSAFAEoK6AD7IUthqItDwSMiOLugQAB6QICSUaNJq+PKkFCCGbLLQqvh6+AiW1MgQTq4U0a7IALyY6uycyABEbQA0BAoUHd2ZigCMAEwAzMj8hchQtoZQVpUxDMgA9KvI5gDWcACe3bWxCRBJKUeJyamBEgJCOKUg5Ut1jTb2VW4ePqrAMMiebUGbWQoAqH28aRKZXMzggADpnOY6J5nqg4YM4WBzABVAAOuOgAGE4JQID5vCt1shSmxcS4IClZIYwMhALwbgFKdggsqDGMwcGRUgAquwJdigUHcAEIwTE4Rp4Vi8QSoMTSSCUiBzCy4MgjCYzJZbvpjSQIAhnHBZtSyizzLIAFZ+ZDXH5-AFAkFWO32iEhfBU73qghBT3IAAW0AgMgelBh8MRyO9cpamJx+KJJLJ3gpAgqzjVfrWG0DwBScCs6FBEdm0ehsIRSM8SaIpFTSozpPJulwQA)

Comment: Hi, I made one correction in interface `A`. It was a typo. Sincere apologies. I want to ignore checking each properties to determine the type . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

for me is easiest way to use discriminant if you are able to change shape of these interfaces.

```
interface A {
  discriminantKey: 'interfaceA';
  a_id: string;
  b_id: string;
}

interface B {
 discriminantKey: 'interfaceB';
 b_id: string;
 name: string;
}
```

and when you ask on your discriminant key in swithc case you will have type guard even in typescript not only runetime.

```
const myType = {...}
switch(myType.discriminantKey) {
  case 'interfaceA':
    // here is type infered to 'A' interface;
   break
  case 'interfaceB':
    // here it is 'b'
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQz-IAmwAzglMALahzgDSEAngFzIDkoksiEqbA3LgLI4AfWCFWJMBRABzQXgIAjcZOTTZC3AF9cuTtHhJkAIUxCCxMhWohaYBi3aHuSUwMv5VEqTNDaSvj2lBB+Wop6OLgIAPYg0sgwIMgAvMgAFAAOcFBwlKzoAD5mAJRpAHwWQRoA7sBgCAAWmTl5lAB01uRUNPRM5dg1wghwJCgc4EY8fMxewgtxCWAiAJKEacht+R1iEvzIAPSHyGCMWSgkcDAoYLHIAK7jADRbufnIpCIANlAQcIRGJ8QDc-hs7qdzihUPMFio-nAANaKOH4UbjFxTNwQDxzYaopaJEIodLbTrEg7HDT5FBNaAQWGo5QI5HzKJRIA)