# check the type of an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this type defined

```
export interface Hostel {
    id: String;
}
```

I want to check if an object is from that type, but there is no way. I have tried with

```
console.log ('************ ', (typeof result === 'Hostel'));
        console.log ('************ ', (typeof result === Hostel));
        console.log ('************ ', result instanceof Hostel);
```

I have this error:

```
'Hostel' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

Comment: what's the output you getting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interface type check with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078205/how-to-check-the-object-type-on-runtime-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

Types (which includes interfaces) are only available during development and compile time and not during runtime. You need to use a [class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) if you want to check the type during runtime.

```
export class Hostel {
    constructor(public id: String){};
}

const result = new Hostel("foo");

console.log(result instanceof Hostel) // this will return true
```