# Javascript type check am I doing it right?

Tags: javascript

-(Edited)This question does not apply to only Numbers, but about all types in general.
I am using something like:

```
exampleFunction1(a,b){
   if(
        Object.prototype.toString.call(a) === "[object Number]" &&
        Object.prototype.toString.call(b) === "[object Number]"
     ){
        return a+b;
     }else{
        console.log('%cType Error : exampleFunction1(<Number>)','color:#00FF66;')
     }
}

exampleFunction2(type,length,format) {
        if(
            Object.prototype.toString.call(type) === "[object String]" &&
            Object.prototype.toString.call(length) === "[object Number]" &&
            (Object.prototype.toString.call(format) === "[object String]" || Object.prototype.toString.call(format) === "[object Undefined]" )
        ){

        }else{
            console.log("%cType Error : exampleFunction2(<String>,<Number>,<String>)","color:#00FF66;")
        }
    }
```

in almost all of my functions to strict check its input type before starting to write my actual code. And its mostly on functions that i'll share amongst my team and on my own library which other people will try to use. Is this considered as a good practice or it's unnecessary ?

Comment: It's far better to use facebook's flow or microsoft's typescript.

Comment: @marco-a the problem of typescript is that it does not check during run time and it breaks some of the es6 syntax, which makes it more time consuming to fix it.

Comment: typescript is compiled to javascript. all checks will be done during run time; though they will be implicit and hidden away

Comment: @richytong You sure ? According to this post's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44078574/10822847 typescript does not check type during run time.

Comment: okay, you got me. thanks for showing me that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find one right answer, but you can find strong opinions. My opinion is: **it varies**. Here are some typechecks from [my library](https://github.com/richytong/rubico)

```js
const isDefined = x => x !== undefined && x !== null

const isUndefined = x => x === undefined

const isNull = x => x === null

const isIterable = x => isDefined(x) && isDefined(x[Symbol.iterator])

const isAsyncIterable = x => isDefined(x) && isDefined(x[Symbol.asyncIterator])

const isReadable = x => x && typeof x.read === 'function'

const isWritable = x => x && typeof x.write === 'function'

const isFunction = x => typeof x === 'function'

const isArray = Array.isArray

const numberTypedArrays = new Set([
  'Uint8ClampedArray',
  'Uint8Array', 'Int8Array',
  'Uint16Array', 'Int16Array',
  'Uint32Array', 'Int32Array',
  'Float32Array', 'Float64Array',
])

const isNumberTypedArray = x => x && x.constructor && (
  numberTypedArrays.has(x.constructor.name)
)

const bigIntTypedArrays = new Set([
  'BigUint64Array', 'BigInt64Array',
])

const isBigIntTypedArray = x => x && x.constructor && (
  bigIntTypedArrays.has(x.constructor.name)
)

const isNumber = x => typeof x === 'number'

const isBigInt = x => typeof x === 'bigint'

const isString = x => typeof x === 'string'

const isPromise = x => x && typeof x.then === 'function'

const is = fn => x => x && x.constructor === fn

const isObject = is(Object) // checks directly for Object, isObject([]) === false
```

If you're looking for a quick way to just check the type given the constructor function, I recommend copy and pasting `is` and using it so

```js
const is = fn => x => x && x.constructor === fn

exampleFunction1(a,b){
   if(is(Number)(a) && is(Number)(b)){
        return a+b;
     }else{
        console.log('%cType Error : exampleFunction1(<Number>)','color:#00FF66;')
     }
}
```

it's less to type.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. Just a question: wouldn't it be much more easier to define Object.prototype.toString.call(<nameHere>) === "[object <typeHere>]" repeatedly rather than having different logic for each type ?

Comment: That actually work very well given that is(Object), is(Array), is(Float32Array) etc works just fine. Is there any type this method won't work on ?

Comment: It unfortunately does not work for `TypedArray` which is hidden from the global namespace. I wanted to do an easy type check for `Uint8Array, Int8Array, ..., Float64Array` as a group, so that's how I arrived at `isNumberTypedArray`. I also ran into a bunch of one off cases like `isDefined` where I want to conveniently check for undefined and null. So i guess that's where all the variation came from for me.

Comment: also when you just want to see if something has a certain method, like `isReadable` just checks for the function `read`. this is [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)

Comment: For the isDefined part. If you entered nothing , is(<someType>)(input) returns "undefined" won't that be enough to check ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `isNaN` method to check is number or not as

```
addNumbers(a,b){
   if(
        !isNaN(a) &&
        !isNaN(b)
     ){
        return a+b;
     }else{
        console.log('%cType Error : findUniqueInArray(<Array>)','color:#00FF66;')
     }
}
```

Comment: `isNaN()` performs soft type check, so for example `isNaN(true)` is `false`.

Comment: `Number.IsNaN` if you want check for input type

Comment: @AluanHaddad `Number.isNaN()` on the other hand returns `true` just for the true `NaN` value. There's no magic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on `toString()` doesn't seem like the safest choice, as any object can implement its own `toString()`.

I'd go with `Number.isFinite()`:

```js
if (Number.isFinite(a) && Number.isFinite(b)) {
```

If you just want to check the type, there's a `typeof` operator:

```js
typeof 1 // "number"
typeof 'a' // "string"
typeof {} // "object"
```

As for the `toString()`, libraries often implement their own `toString()` to help you debug. Here's how it's done with classes:

```js
class Foo {
    toString() {
        return 'I am mr. Foo';
     }
}

const bar = new Foo();
bar.toString() // "I am mr. Foo"
```

Comment: This question is not only about numbers, but also for other types. Also can you give an example of "as any object can implement its own toString()."?

Comment: Updated my answer to explain.

Comment: typeof is unreliable because typeof Object and typeof Array returns the same result

Comment: Yup, it's not good for arrays. There's no one liner for all the types. If you wanna be type safe, use TypeScript, as suggested.

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)` never calls `obj.toString` so that is not an issue.

Comment: Well, yeah - unless somebody plays with the Object prototype globally you are right. But I don't think anyone should do any speculations relying on `toString()`.

Comment: @RoboRobok According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray given "isArray" as an example, the type check performed internally is actually Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Array]'; . Does it means that the check in this is unreliable?

Comment: They aren't saying it's done like that internally. They suggest such a polyfill, but Mozilla's polyfills are often far from perfect. You know, you can use `toString()` if you really want to, I'm just saying it's a bad practice in my opinion, because it can be anything. But if you check types a lot, you really should check out TypeScript. The code gets quite ugly with type checks inside methods.

Comment: Ok i see what you mean there. But i just don't quite see the problem of using "Object.prototype.toString" , in the example given by you. if you console.log Object.prototype.toString(bar) it does not return [object String], it returns [object Object] which actually does it job preventing variables other than String into the function

Comment: It's one of these situations where you can do it and be safe, but it's not considered a great way to go. I don't think there's any standard of what `toString()` should be. All popular implementations of JS engine will be the same, but in theory they don't need to be. It's up to you how much of an idealist you feel today :)