# How could typescript check object attribute type at runtime

Tags: typescript

I defined a `service type` and my purpose is to create a function with two params.

- **first** one is service type which is key of type Service
- **second** one is a string array of the attribute keys per the first argument.

something like below

```js
type MyService = {
  service1: { x: string, y: number },
  service2: { m: string, n: number },
};

function useService(ns: keyof MyService, serviceNames: Array<keyof MyService[typeof ns extends keyof MyService ? typeof ns : never]>): void {
  console.log(serviceNames);
}

useService('service1', ['x', 'y']);  // now the second parameter type is always never
```

I don't know whether ts could check the runtime type? Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the solution you might want to.

use generic to get type from argments.

```
type MyService = {
  service1: { x: string, y: number },
  service2: { m: string, n: number },
};

function useService<T extends keyof MyService>(ns: T, serviceNames: Array<keyof MyService[T]>): void {
  console.log(serviceNames);
}

useService('service1', ['x', 'y']); // it'll remove the error
```

Answer (score 0):

No Typescript cant check this at runtime sadly...

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44078574/6306152) might be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

Typescript code when it gets compiled, the resultant JS code never has types. So it cannot check at runtime.

```
"use strict";
function useService(ns, serviceNames) {
    console.log(serviceNames);
}
useService('service1', ['x', 'y']);
```