# How to check if data has a defined type in ternary operator Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to check if some data has the correct type before passing it as props to a component. I tried this way but it gives an error `Teacher' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`:

```js
const renderSearchResult = () => {
        switch (true) {
            case searchFilter.groups:
                return <GroupInfos groupData={typeof searchResult === Group ? searchResult : null} />
            case searchFilter.teachers:
                return <AddTeacher teacher={typeof searchResult === Teacher ? searchResult : null} mode={MODAL_MODE.update} />
            default:
                return <AddStudentModal student={typeof searchResult === Student ? searchResult : null} mode={MODAL_MODE.update} />
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `typeof` operator always returns a string, but you probably want `instanceof` (i.e. `searchResult instanceof Group ? ...`). I suggest doing this logic in the receiving component rather than the TSX, as it doesn't seem like something the view should care about.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will move the logic to the receiving comp. I tried   `instanceof` but I still get the same error message from vscode.

Comment: Can you put your code on Playground

Comment: @B.Mohammad Please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078205/how-to-check-the-object-type-on-runtime-in-typescript

Comment: I'm guessing `Teacher` is an `interface`. If it is, can you include `Teacher` in the question?

Comment: @programmerRaj `Teacher` is a type, its in the question already :`return <AddTeacher teacher={typeof searchResult === Teacher ? searchResult : null} mode={MODAL_MODE.update} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `in` operator to check if the type has a specific attribute in it,

I did like this:

```js
const renderSearchResult = () => {
    let checkedData: Group | Teacher | Student | null
    switch (true) {
      case searchFilter.groups:
        checkedData = checkTypeData('subject')
        return <GroupInfos groupData={checkedData && checkedData as Group} />

      case searchFilter.teachers:
        checkedData = checkTypeData('rate')
        return (
          <AddTeacher
            hide={() => setSearchResult(null)}
            teacher={checkedData && checkedData as Teacher}
            mode={MODAL_MODE.update}
            displayType={DisplayType.DEFAULT}
          />
        )

      default:
        checkedData = checkTypeData('payments')
        return (
          <AddStudentModal
            student={checkedData && checkedData as Student}
            mode={MODAL_MODE.update}
          />
        )
    }
  }

    const checkTypeData = (key: string) => {
        if (key in searchResult) {
            return searchResult
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }

//// types:
//========

export type Group = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  subject: string;
  level: string;
  teacher: Teacher;
  students: Student[];
  year: string;
  semester: number;
};

export type Teacher = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  fullName: string;
  groupIds: GroupId[];
  rate: Rate;
};


export type Student = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  fullName: string;
  groupIds: string[];
  payments: Payment[];
};
```

Did still looks too much, I need a better and simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I think you want to:

1. *narrow* the type of `searchResult` so that typescript will understand what type it is after you check for some differentiating property and
2. filter the result to the right component according to it's type

Building on B. Mohammad's answer above, use `in`, but use it in a [type-guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to get type safety as well:

```
function isTeacher(searchResult: Group | Teacher | Student): is Teacher {
    return 'rate' in searchResult;
}
```

Then you can use it in your render function like so:

```
const renderSearchResult = () => {
        switch (true) {
            ...
            case searchFilter.teachers:
                return <AddTeacher teacher={isTeacher(searchResult) ? searchResult : null} mode={MODAL_MODE.update} />
            ...
        }
    }
```