# Typescript: Use value as key in type definition

Tags: typescript

I get data from a server in the following format and I would like to define its type. I am struggling to define one of the keys as it depends on value of another key. Is it possible to define this type correctly or come a bit closer than just `any`?

Pseudo-code below

```
type Data = {
    result: string;
    url: string;
    [key: result]: { // <- ERROR. The key should be the value of the result key above. 
        message: string;
    };
};
```

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible

Comment: The idea of typescriopt is to do static typing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is; "you can't"

Comment: Liam, if it will (maybe never), then users won’t be able to answer this

Comment: I believe there are ways to be more explicit with the Type of responses you get with an API, which will then make this a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible as you expect, because that's not why typescript is made for, Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44078574/8667766) about types at runtime with typescript

> Types are stripped away at compile-time and do not exist at runtime,
> so you can't check the type at runtime.

Personally, if you can't know the type of some property until run time, I'd suggest using [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup#yuplazyvalue-any--schema-lazy) lazy method if you can find that possible for your case.

Comment: What you seem to be essentially saying here is that this question is a duplicate?

Comment: I'm also not really sure what this has to do with the actual question. Yes Typescript is a superset of Javascript, yes JS has no types and tyescript is compiled to JS. None of this is really relevant

Comment: He wants the types of typescript to be lazily defined at runtime based on some API return value, that is currently impossible because typescript made for author time compiling, so I made a ref to another answer because I didn't find a simple duplicated question, and give a suggestion that he can choose for himself if that is feasible or not.