# Create inputs based on type keys

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So, I want to create a component which will create some inputs, needed for creating an entity in the back-end.

For this, I have two ideas:

1st

```
Create a component which takes a type as a prop
Pass the type to the prop
Iterate over its keys
For each key, create an input
```

For this approach, my component looks like this:

```
import { Type } from "typescript";

type Props = {
    dataType: Type
}

export default function CreateRow(props: Props) {
  return (
    <div>//iteration over keys</div>
  );  
}
```

and the component would be called like this:

```
import type {EducatieItem} from './EducatieItem';

        <CreateRow dataType={EducatieItem}/>
```

but this doesn't work. I get

```
'EducatieItem' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

EducatieItem is

```
export type EducatieItem = {
    id: string,
    name: string
};
```

The other idea was to create a generic component, like this:

```
export default function CreateRow<T>() {
  return (
    <div>//iteration over keys</div>
  );  
}
```

and the call:

```
        <CreateRow<EducatieItem>/>
```

this doesn't throw any error... yet.

If I actually try to iterate over the keys of T, then I will get the same error as before.

Is there any way to achieve what I want? Are any of my approaches valid though?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check the object type on runtime in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078205/how-to-check-the-object-type-on-runtime-in-typescript)

Comment: @Etheryte no, it doesn't, sorry

Comment: It does though? Types don't exist at runtime so you can't iterate over them at runtime. That's also what your error message is telling you, you can't use a type as a value.

Comment: "Is there any way to achieve what I want? Are any of my approaches valid though?" - it partially answers it, ruling out my first approach only. Would you mind showing me how would you achieve what I proposed, please?

Comment: Your second approach is the same as the first one, just in a different syntactic way. You can't iterate over data that's not there. This isn't possible out of the box with Typescript. You can see further discussion under [this ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3628) with some proposals on how to sidestep the issue.

Comment: @Etheryte I see. What would your approach be in my situation though? Would you just send the input fields' name as an array, for example?