# Property 'Error' does not exist on type 'MovieData | ResponseError'. Property 'Error' does not exist on type 'MovieData'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Answered

So I have following interfaces: MovieData

```
export interface MovieData {
  Poster: string;
  Title: string;
  Plot: string;
  imdbID: string;
}
```

and interface ResponseError

```
export interface ResponseError {
  Response: 'False',
  Error: string,
}
```

I also have function getMovie() thet returns Promise, resolve type is MovieData , and reject type is ResponseError

```
import { MovieData } from './types/MovieData';
import { ResponseError } from './types/ReponseError';

const API_URL = 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=**********';

export function getMovie(query: string): Promise<MovieData | ResponseError> {
  return fetch(`${API_URL}&t=${query}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(() => ({
      Response: 'False',
      Error: 'unexpected error',
    }));
}
```

In FindMovie function component I invoke handleSubmit function, and pass search string inside getMovie function. In then() method of promise I want to check either promise was rejected , or fullfiled. In case rejected - I check if res object has property Error.
type of res - if you hover mouse over res property in then() - res: MovieData | ResponseError

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { getMovie } from '../../api';

export const FindMovie: React.FC = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState<string>('');
  const [error, setError] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (search === '') {
      return;
    }

    getMovie(search)
      .then(res => {
        if (res?.Error) {
          console.log(res?.Error)
        }
      });

    setError(false);
  };
```

QUESTION!!!!!!!!

in terminal I recieve error:
Property 'Error' does not exist on type 'MovieData | ResponseError'.
Property 'Error' does not exist on type 'MovieData'.

I tried to use import separetly interface ResponseError to file with findMovie function component

```
import { ResponseError } from '../../types/ReponseError';
```

and to perform next check

```
.then(res => {
   if (res instanceof ResponseError) {
       console.log(res?.Error)
   }
});
```

But I recieve even wierder error message: Attempted import error: 'ResponseError' is not exported from '../../types/ReponseError'.

Will be glad for every advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a type guard here to check if your object is of type `ResponseError`.

You cannot use `instanceof` here, since that is used to check if an object belongs to a certain `class`.

Whereas in your case, you are using `interface` and `type`.

Defining a type guard like:

```
function isResponseError(obj: any): obj is ResponseError {
    return obj.Error !== undefined;
}
```

and then doing:

```
.then(res => {
   if (isResponseError(res)) {
       console.log(res.Error)
   }
});
```

should solve your problem.

You can check out this stackoverflow answer for more info on type guards vs `instanceof`: [How to check the object type on runtime in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078205/how-to-check-the-object-type-on-runtime-in-typescript)

**EDIT**: Replying to your [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73199871/14332340):

That's also a decent way to go about it!

Allow me to recommend another approach.
Your `MovieData` type could be:

```
export interface MovieData {
  data?: {
    Poster: string;
    Title: string;
    Plot: string;
    imdbID: string;
  }
  error?: {
    Response: 'False',
    Error: string,
  }
}
```

Then in your `getMovies` function:

1. If there is no error > you could set set the `data` field to the appropriate values .
2. Else > you could set the `error` field to the error coming from the API

And in your frontend you can check for something like:

```
if (res.error !== undefined) {
  setError(true);
}
```

This might be a cleaner approach since

- Its more obvious that you are checking for an error if you do `res.error === something` rather than `res.title === something`
- I've seen several APIs (eg. Apollo client, Stripe APIs) handle
  sending errors and data from an API call in this way, which is why I recommend this as best practice.

Comment: Btw, do hide your API key from public posts such as this one. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Your solution in edited section is way better then  one that I put in answer.
I have already rewritten my code  utilising yuor proposed MovieData interface.
Again , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, thats how I implemented type guard

```
if (res?.Title === undefined) {
  setError(true);
}
```

But I also completly rewrote fetch request. Honestly , now its wierd , `result` variable will be of Type MovieData errelevent of object content. But it Just Works.

In the question problem was: I was checking for property of `Moviedata` type object - typescript said that `ResponseError` interface doesn't have that property - because promise returned object of either `MovieData` or `ResponseError`;

```
export async function getMovie(query: string): Promise<MovieData > {
  const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}&t=${query}`);
  const result = await res.json();

  if (result.response === 'False') {
    throw new Error(`${result.statusText}`);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: I've edited my answer above as a reply to this :)