# Is there any way to reassign the type of property of a class according to passing argument type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typeof, keyof

I am trying to dynamically assign type of a static property in a class.
And use the `typeof`, `keyof` and other features of typescript further.

Here is my code

```js
class Neith {
    static config: any;
    static Loader<T>(conf: T) {
        Neith.config=conf;
    }
    static Log(v:(keyof (typeof Neith.config))) {
        console.log(Neith.config[v]);
    }
}

const obj = {
    a: 'A',
    b: 'B',
}
Neith.Loader(obj);
Neith.Log('a');
```

I am expecting the `Neith.Log` method suggest me `a | b` type of the parameter

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44078574/989920

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's not really at runtime, because every value can be deduced from the code, but typescript isn't smart enough I guess

Comment: Not really, the best I can think of is using a function to create the class, and pass the type down..  Something like -> `const Neith = makeNeith(obj);`,   `Neith` could then be  a class with the correct types.

Comment: Example of @Keith's idea https://tsplay.dev/N75zBW

Comment: You can also use generic class https://tsplay.dev/Nr832W

Answer (score 2):

as static members cannot reference class type parameters, I would suggest to use a function that define a generic template in your class like this:

```
function Neith<T> (){
 class Neith {
  static config: T;
  static Loader(conf: T) {
    Neith.config = conf;
  }
  static Log(v: keyof T) {
    console.log("param :"+ Neith.config[v]);
  }
}

return Neith
}
```

The parameters take the type from the function template type and not the class so the returned class will not be with generic types.

Then you can use the function directly :

```
const obj = {
      a: 'hello a ',
      b: 'hello b',
    }
    
    let neithClass = Neith<typeof obj>()
    
    neithClass.Loader(obj);
    neithClass.Log('a');
```

Or extend the class returned by the function like this :

```
const obj = {
          a: 'hello a ',
          b: 'hello b',
        }

class NeithForObj extends Neith<typeof obj>(){}
        
NeithForObj.Loader(obj);
NeithForObj.Log('a');
```