# Next.js 14 API Handler - Proper Request JSON body validation

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to build an api for an iOS app I'm working on. I'm using Next.js 14 for it and I got it working, for the most part but I'm a bit puzzled on how to properly validate the body of a `Request`. `ESLint` throws all kinds of errors and warnings at me and while I could "fix" most of them, there's one I'm really unsure about:

> Unsafe assignment of an `any` value

This happens when I say `const body = await request.json();`. I don't understand how to fix this. The `json()` method returns `any` at this point but it's immediately validated by calling `validateRequest` one line later.

I could cast it as `RequestBody`: `const body = await request.json() as RequestBody;` but that kind of defeats the point, doesn't it?

Any ideas how to properly handle this?

```js
// app/api/route.tsx

interface RequestBody {
  name: string;
}

function validateRequest(object: any): object is RequestBody {
  return (
    (object as RequestBody) && typeof (object as RequestBody).name === "string"
  );
}

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  try {
    // Warning: Unsafe assignment of an `any` value
    const body = await request.json();

    if (!validateRequest(body)) {
      return new Response("Invalid Data", { status: 400 });
    }

    return Response.json({ message: body.name });
  } catch {
    return new Response("Bad Request", { status: 400 });
  }
}
```

I've followed this answer for runtime validation of the data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44078574/3134192

Comment: I suggest you to use validation library like Zod. I use it everywhere.

Comment: Oh wow that actually works really well! So it's just `const body = RequestBody.parse(await request.json());` and all warnings are gone. Thanks! Do you want to post an answer so that I can mark it as solved? Here's the final code that works: https://gist.github.com/SwiftedMind/d15a8a7d0a4d8441fb3b11be25f24a0f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use validation library such as Zod, Yup or Valibot. Using Zod you define your schema and you can validate the body with .parse or other methods. You can find more examples in the official docs.

Define your schema:

```
const User = z.object({
   name: z.string()
});
```

Then you can validate the body with parse or safe parse method:

```
// will throw and error if body is not valid
User.parse({ username: "Ludwig" });

// will return object with properties: {success: boolean, error: ZodError}
User.safeParse({ username: "Ludwig" });
```

Zod does much more you can even infer a type from your schema:

```
// extract the inferred type
type User = z.infer<typeof User>
```