# filter array depending on it's type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings

I'm new to typescript ... I have an array which it's type is a union of two types typeA[] | typeB[] but I want to filter depending on the type of the object

```
interface TypeA {
  attribute1: string
  attribute2: string
}

interface TypeB {
  attribute3: string
  attribute4: string
}

function fitlerFunc(obj: TypeA[] | TypeB[]) {
  if(/*obj is TypeA */) {
    return obj.filter(item => item.attribute1 === 'test')
  }

  if(/*obj is TypeB */) {
    return obj.filter(item => item.attribute3 === 'something')
  }
}
```

or if there is a way to know which type of array I receive

Comment: Typescript types don't exist at runtime, so you will need a way to either identify the type of input based on its properties, parameters, or other similar options.

Comment: yeah but when I try to access one of the properties I have typescript error that this property doesn't exist on the other type

Comment: Please [edit] to provide a [mre] and try to use conventional names. Right now we don't have access to `typeA` and `typeB`  and those should probably be `TypeA` and `TypeB` to distinguish them from variable names.  You can tell if something's a [mre] by pasting it into a standalone IDE and seeing if it demonstrates your issue without introducing other ones.

Comment: no it doesn't I updated the example of the probleme I have, I need to know how to replace the if conditions in the example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check the object type on runtime in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078205/how-to-check-the-object-type-on-runtime-in-typescript)

Comment: Yess I read that its the guard type, but in my case it is about an array not a simple object

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mxErXW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (and please edit to change "fitler" to "filter", since the former is quite unfortunate). If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

An plain array itself has no attributes that can be used to discriminate its elements' types.

However, you can use a [functional type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to validate at runtime that the array's elements conform to the expected type, then safely perform the property access operation inside the filter callback function:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwE6uQTwJJQKYC2AzgBLIBueACqnAA56pSYA8VieAHvmACZGIa9RswDSeTAD4AFACgAkGgyYAXIjgAjAFZ5oAbQC6AGgV1adNVRMBKNUqyIYAgEq64qXmyOJwAazBwAO5gkoaIAN4KqHhQIKhI9pgAdHiUqJjS0nDWiAC8kohm9I5I2QDcsgC+srIwYPiowMgQeIgAKpgMAIIRCshQUKgwGiD4AIxqRIN1AOYVigNDI-gATJPTYHNVNXUNTS3tnXgAQr0L08t4AMzrQ5vz-RejeAAst7MV1bKgkLAIiMAYFAADaMABi4AgWW0ag63TCAB9DgxjoYcpF5DBgIhpIlcIRSBRqOYRBlNFpvAAiR5LZ5jSnWdEKeTRWLxdTaJKA4ENTJAwg5fKOfAEJI04Z0vK5XKISn4KYM+byAD0ysQ6vVAD0APwKaosmJxUqc7m86T8giCgoWsWLCX4K5SmWUohwAgxAAWs0VClVGq1uuqQA)

```ts
function arrayItemsHaveProperty<P extends PropertyKey>(
  array: object[],
  prop: P,
): array is Record<P, unknown>[] {
  return array.every((o) => prop in o);
}

interface TypeA {
  attribute1: string;
  attribute2: string;
}

interface TypeB {
  attribute3: string;
  attribute4: string;
}

function fitlerFunc(obj: TypeA[] | TypeB[]) {
  if (arrayItemsHaveProperty(obj, "attribute1")) {
    return obj.filter((item) => item.attribute1 === "test");
    //     ^? (parameter) obj: TypeA[]
  }
  return obj.filter((item) => item.attribute3 === "something");
  //     ^? (parameter) obj: TypeB[]
}
```

> Note that this approach prefers simpler syntax over performance (two iterations of the array) — you could do it in a single iteration, but [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) would be required. The trade-off depends on the details of your actual use case.